# Creating a matrix containing a filled ellipse based on a non-contiguous outline

Tags: matlab, ellipse, flood-fill

I'm trying to create a matrix of 0 values, with 1 values filling a ellipse shape. My ellipse was generated using minVolEllipse.m ([Link 1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9542-minimum-volume-enclosing-ellipsoid)) which returns a matrix of the ellipse equation in the 'center form' and the center of the ellipse. I then use a snippet of code from Ellipse_plot.m (from the aforementioned link) to parameterize the vector into major/minor axes, generate a parametric equation, and generate a matrix of transformed coordinates. You can see their code to see how this is done. The result is a matrix that has index locations for points along the ellipse. It does not encompass every value along the outline of the ellipse unless I set the number of grid points, N, to a ridiculously high value.

When I use the MATLAB plot or patch commands I see exactly the result I'm looking for. However, I want this represented as a matrix of 0 values with 1s where patch 'fills in' the blanks. It is apparent that MATLAB has this functionality, but I have yet to find the code to execute it. What I am looking for is similar to how bwfill of the image processing toolbox works ([Link 2](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/images/bwfill.html)). bwfill does not work for me because my ellipse is not contiguous, so the function returns a matrix filled completely with 1 values.

Hopefully I have outlined the problem well enough, if not please comment and I can edit the post to clarify.

EDIT:

I have devised a strategy using the 2-D X vector from Ellipse_plot.m as an input to EllipseDirectFit.m ([Link 3](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22684-ellipse-fit-direct-method)). This function returns the coefficients for the ellipse function ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+dy+f=0. Using these coefficients I calculate the angle between the x-axis and the major axis of the ellipse. This angle, along with the center and major/minor axes are passed into ellipseMatrix.m ([Link 4](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17499-drawing-an-ellipse-into-a-matrix-image)), which returns a filled matrix. Unfortunately, the matrix appears to be out of rotation from what I want. Here is the portion of my code:

```
N = 20; %Number of grid points in ellipse
ellipsepoints = clusterpoints(clusterpoints(:,1)==i,2:3)';
[A,C]         = minVolEllipse(ellipsepoints,0.001,N);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%Adapted from:
%  Ellipse_plot.m
%  Nima Moshtagh
%  nima@seas.upenn.edu
%  University of Pennsylvania
%  Feb 1, 2007
%  Updated: Feb 3, 2007
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%
% "singular value decomposition" to extract the orientation and the
% axes of the ellipsoid
%------------------------------------
[U D V] = svd(A);

%
% get the major and minor axes
%------------------------------------
a = 1/sqrt(D(1,1))
b = 1/sqrt(D(2,2))

%theta values
theta = [0:1/N:2*pi+1/N];

%
% Parametric equation of the ellipse
%----------------------------------------
state(1,:) = a*cos(theta); 
state(2,:) = b*sin(theta);

%
% Coordinate transform 
%----------------------------------------
X = V * state;
X(1,:) = X(1,:) + C(1);
X(2,:) = X(2,:) + C(2);

% Output: Elip_Eq = [a b c d e f]' is the vector of algebraic 
%       parameters of the fitting ellipse:
Elip_Eq = EllipseDirectFit(X')
% http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html gives the equation for finding the angle theta (teta).
% The coefficients from EllipseDirectFit are rescaled to match what is expected in the wolfram link.
Elip_Eq(2) = Elip_Eq(2)/2;
Elip_Eq(4) = Elip_Eq(4)/2;
Elip_Eq(5) = Elip_Eq(5)/2;

if Elip_Eq(2)==0
    if Elip_Eq(1) < Elip_Eq(3)
        teta = 0;
    else
        teta = (1/2)*pi;
    endif
else
    tetap = (1/2)*acot((Elip_Eq(1)-Elip_Eq(3))/(Elip_Eq(2)));
    if Elip_Eq(1) < Elip_Eq(3)
        teta = tetap;
    else
        teta = (pi/2)+tetap;
    endif
endif

blank_mask = zeros([height width]);

if teta < 0
    teta = pi+teta;
endif

%I may need to switch a and b, depending on which is larger (so that the fist is the major axis)
filled_mask1 = ellipseMatrix(C(2),C(1),b,a,teta,blank_mask,1);
```

EDIT 2:

As a response to the suggestion from @BenVoigt, I have written a for-loop solution to the problem, here:

```
N = 20; %Number of grid points in ellipse
ellipsepoints = clusterpoints(clusterpoints(:,1)==i,2:3)';
[A,C]         = minVolEllipse(ellipsepoints,0.001,N);

filled_mask = zeros([height width]);
for y=0:1:height
   for x=0:1:width
      point = ([x;y]-C)'*A*([x;y]-C);
      if point < 1
         filled_mask(y,x) = 1;
      endif
   endfor
endfor
```

Although this is technically a solution to the problem, I am interested in a non-iterative solution. I'm running this script over many large images, and need it to be very fast and parallel.

EDIT 3:

Thanks @mathematical.coffee for this solution:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:width,0:height);
fill_mask=arrayfun(@(x,y) ([x;y]-C)'*A*([x;y]-C),X,Y) < 1;
```

However, I believe there is yet a better way to do this. Here is a for-loop implementation that I did that runs faster than both above attempts:

```
ellip_mask = zeros([height width]);
[U D V] = svd(A);
a = 1/sqrt(D(1,1));
b = 1/sqrt(D(2,2));
maxab = ceil(max(a,b));

xstart = round(max(C(1)-maxab,1));
xend = round(min(C(1)+maxab,width));
ystart = round(max(C(2)-maxab,1));
yend = round(min(C(2)+maxab,height));

for y = ystart:1:yend
   for x = xstart:1:xend
      point = ([x;y]-C)'*A*([x;y]-C);
      if point < 1
         ellip_mask(y,x) = 1;
      endif
   endfor
endfor
```

Is there a way to accomplish this goal (the total image size is still [width height]) without this for-loop? The reason this is faster is because I don't have to iterate over the entire image to determine if my point is within the ellipse. Instead, I can simply iterate over a square region that is the length of the center +/- the largest principle axis.

Comment: I'm trying to use the interp function to connect the ellipse now, but it is not working

Comment: Why not skip the outline, and simply evaluate each point (`meshgrid` will help) in your matrix to see whether it's in the interior of the ellipse?

Comment: I did not mention that I am looking for a non-iterative procedure for this, although ellipseMatrix.m uses a loop. A method that avoids loops is preferred as performance is a major concern.

Comment: You can vectorise your for-loop using `[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:width,0:height); filled_mask=arrayfun(@(x,y) ([x; y]-C)'*A*([x;y]-C) , X, Y) < 1;`. But if your images are say ~5000xwhatever this may still take too long (but most things will take too long on images that size anyway?)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution @mathematical.coffee, this is exactly what I am looking for. I devised a for-loop solution (posted in the original question) that will run faster. Can you think of a way to use arrayfun to accomplish the same result as my faster implementation? I have been trying to get a grasp on how meshgrid and arrayfun can work together, but it is still unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the matrix multiply, which is an elliptic norm, gives a fairly simply vectorized expression:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:width,0:height);
X = X - C(1);
Y = Y - C(2);
fill_mask = X.^2 * A(1,1) + X.*Y * (A(1,2) + A(2,1)) + Y.^2 * A(2,2) < 1;
```

This is what I intended by my original comment.